# find if there is a common string between 2 list of strings using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Lists of strings:

```
List<string> lotterynumber;
List<string> lotterywinningnumber;
```

I want to see if a `lotterynumber` is within the `lotterywinningnumber`.

I am using a `foreach` loop right now:

```
bool b = false;
foreach(string s in lotterynumber)
{
    if(lotterywinningnumber.contains(s))
    {
        b= true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can do it in Linq?

Comment: Is it 2 strings or 2 `List<string>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx). It will return a new Enumerable containing the items that exist in both collections.

```
var lotteryNumbers = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
var lotteryWinningNumbers = new List<string>() { "2", "3", "5" };
var numbersInBoth = lotteryNumbers.Intersect(lotteryWinningNumbers); // { "2", "3" }
```

From MSDN:

> The intersection of two sets A and B is defined as the set that contains all the elements of A that also appear in B, but no other elements. When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect enumerates first, collecting all distinct elements of that sequence. It then enumerates second, marking those elements that occur in both sequences. Finally, the marked elements are yielded in the order in which they were collected.

The benefit to using `Intersect` is that it will return the values that exist in both collections, instead of just a Boolean value.

Obviously, if a Boolean value is what you need, you just have to check if the resulting collection contains any elements:

```
bool contains = lotteryNumbers.Intersect(lotteryWinningNumbers).Any();
```

Comment: `bool contains = lotteryNumbers.Intersect(lotteryWinningNumbers).Any()` is a better choice that allows early short-circuitting.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but the efficiency will be the same: O(n).

Use Any

```
bool b = lotterynumber.Any(a => lotterywinningnumber.Contains(a));
```

Comment: The efficiency will **not** necessarily be the same. In his example, he is iterating through each item in the collection. `Any` stops as soon as it finds an element which satisfies the condition. From the MSDN docs: [The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) The Big O runtime, however, **will** be the same on the *average* case. Both are O(n).

Comment: I agree, that is what I meant. - You are true, that I wasn't precise enough, when I didn't say, that I mean asymptotically. - Which is what is usually meant when talking about time consumption of algorithms.

Comment: It's the same if the OP added a `break` inside of the `if`.